# How is Map stage and Reduce stage progress calculated

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to know how the map-stage and reduce stage-progress is calculated when a job is running in Hadoop MapReduce.

[image]

I went into JobClient.java to search for clues and I think JobStatus.java stores all this information but I could not find how the percentage is calculated/updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress#updateTaskStatus`:

```
 double progressDelta = tip.getProgress() - oldProgress;
 if (tip.isMapTask()) {
    this.status.setMapProgress((float) (this.status.mapProgress() + 
                                progressDelta / maps.length));
 } else {
  this.status.setReduceProgress((float) (this.status.reduceProgress() + 
                              (progressDelta / reduces.length)));
 }
```

Basically, it is the averaged progress across all the tasks.

Comment: How does it define progress ? I mean what is this fraction really? Is it the number of records processed / total records?

Comment: Where are the variables for total number of records and records processed for both map and reduce, if I want to use them somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Look for this file

https://github.com/shot/hadoop-source-reading/blob/master/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.java

Check for function , which shows % status. you need to check for mapProgress and reduceProgress

```
  public boolean monitorAndPrintJob
  .....
  while (!job.isComplete()) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        String report = (" map "
                + StringUtils.formatPercent(job.mapProgress(), 0)
                + " reduce " + StringUtils.formatPercent(job
                .reduceProgress(), 0));
        if (!report.equals(lastReport)) {
            LOG.info(report);
            lastReport = report;
        }
```

Then u need to look for updateTaskStatus method from 
**org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress**

Comment: That's how it's displayed, not how it's calculated.